# Trying to understand a simple statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

```
#define IS_IPHONE5 (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)?NO:YES)
```

I use the above to check if the user is using iPhone 5 but I don't really understand how it works.

Common sense tells me that if the user screen bounds is X - 568 = 0 the user is using iPhone 5.
But in the above statement 0 will be a NO BOOL and so don't understand how it returns a YES.

Comment: This will work, as others have explained, but it is so pretentious.  It is like whoever wrote this code is going out of their way to make the code unreadable.  Why not just say `([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.f)` ??

Comment: @borrrden I have no idea and think the same way (unless there is something that i'm missing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(0 ? "yes" : "no")` results in `"no"`.

`(0 ? "no" : "yes")` results in `"yes"`.

The expression following the `?` is the result when the boolean expression is true. The expression following the `:` is the result when the boolean expression is false.

Answer (score 2):

it means :

```
if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)
    return NO;
return YES;
```

IPHONE5 height is 568 , so `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568 = 0` , `0` means `NO`, others means `YES`

Comment: @modifiablelvalue it must be returns , such as you maybe code `int a = _yourBool?3:5`;but you never code like : `_yourBool?3:5`,because it is no useful

Comment: I think we have different definitions of "return". My definition is exclusively reserved for the behaviour of `return` in C, and by that definition, the ternary operator certainly doesn't return. If it did, then `int main(void) { char *str = 0 ? "false" : "true"; puts(str); }` wouldn't print anything, because main would return before it reaches the `puts(...);` statement.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue I am very sorry, you are right , we have different definitions of "return". maybe I said "result =" is more suitable

Comment: I don't think the ternary operator *assigns to resu*... Eh, never mind. +1 because this answer *is* better than Rajan's answer.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue +1 for you too, because your answer is more better than me

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple,

You had already solved the logic, Yes it will say Zero, on Zero it will return **YES**.

Because in programming ZERO MEANS FALSE ! So False will return "YES"

and whereas non-zero means TRUE ! So TRUE will return "NO"

Ternary operator is used here , which will work in the above mentioned manner.

Comment: Yea, but why 0 returns YES ?

Comment: Because in programming 0 means FALSE and false will return the latter value which is YES :)

Comment: @EXEC_BAD_ACCESS because 0 evaluates to false. Anything else is true. In ternary operator, if statement is false, latter will be returned (and if it's true, former will be returned). In the case of NO:YES, YES is latter, and therefore YES is returned.

Answer (score 0):

first ,some statement like this:"isTrue?NO:YES",it means that ,when the statement before "?"is really ture,the whole statement(isTrue?NO:YES) value is "NO",else the value is "YES";here,the value of this statement ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568) can be Zero or NON Zero,so when the  [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height equal 568,the above statement is Zero,Zero means false,so it return "YES".